# OpenGL ES 2.0 coordinate system

Tags: opengl-es

I use opengl es 2.0 on iphone render a primitive,I use the shader and glFramebufferTexture2D render to texture, but the results are not the same and I expect, I found the whole coordinates are in turmoil, the vertex data I give is this V0 (-1, -1, -1) V1 (0 , -1,01), V2 (-1,0, -1) I expected result should be first image like this, but the result is indeed like the second iamge case. I found the whole coordinate system like this green arrows along the fold of the same, please tell me how this is true?
[image: first image]

[image: second image]

ok,I found the problem,if I don't use glFramebufferTexture2D,this result is right like the third image .so who can tell me why?

[image: third]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the true coordinate system in the openGL works so that left and bottom are at -1, right and top are at 1. The next thing is the render buffer origin is also in the "bottom-left" corner. So what happens is when you present an image to the screen you want the Y coordinate to be inverted so that the top is at -1 or rather yet at 0, but this is only for a display.

As it goes for textures you should not try to invert it but rather keep the origin at bottom left part. You must understand that once drawn to the texture those pixels are simply RGBA pixel data and when the texture is reused for display (or if you read those pixels) they will be upside-down looking from a natural perspective.

I am not sure all of this is logical enough but what you usually do is invert the scene so what you see is correct but all of this has nothing to do with the actual order of the buffer on the GPU. For instance if you were able to simply replace the RGBA data of the first pixel in the buffer, that pixel would in fact be at the bottom left part of your screen and not your top left.

So it is best to keep the openGL order of things when dealing with the FBO and invert the scene only when drawing to the buffer which will be presented to the screen.

Comment: Now the question is, if I direct rendering, and I expected the same result, if I rendering to a texture(Use glFramebufferTexture2D) and appearance position is not the same as I expected.